# How Should Fortuna and Yarrow Compare When Tested With Dieharder

Tags: random-number-generator, randomness, pseudo-random-generator, fortuna

I have both [Yarrow](http://href=%22https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yarrow_algorithm) and [Fortuna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortuna_(PRNG)) implemented as number generators. I ran 100 complete [DieHarder](https://people.cs.umass.edu/~emery/pubs/ccs03-novark.pdf) (entropy tester) tests for each implementation using the same entropy source. The results were surprising: Fortuna doesn't perform as well as Yarrow.

The results show marginally worse results when generating with Fortuna.

Is the purpose of using the Fortuna PRNG more about security and preventing a 'seed leakage' than it is about the 'quality' of its generated random values?

As requested, here are the results from 100 samples:

```
Fortuna
Test Name                                    PASSED    WEAK    POOR    FAILED
-----------------------------------------  --------  ------  ------  --------
RGB Bit Distribution Test                        97       3       0         0
RGB Bit Distribution Test                        96       3       1         0
RGB Bit Distribution Test                        98       2       0         0
RGB Bit Distribution Test                        98       2       0         0
RGB Bit Distribution Test                        97       3       0         0
RGB Bit Distribution Test                        97       3       0         0
RGB Bit Distribution Test                        95       3       2         0
RGB Bit Distribution Test                        97       2       1         0
RGB Bit Distribution Test                        97       3       0         0
RGB Bit Distribution Test                        98       1       1         0
RGB Bit Distribution Test                        94       6       0         0
RGB Bit Distribution Test                        87       8       5         0
Diehard(er) Birthdays Test                       95       3       2         0
Diehard OPERM5 Test                              17      18      45        20
Diehard 32x32 Binary Rank Test                  100       0       0         0
Diehard 6x8 Binary Rank Test                     89      10       1         0
Diehard Bitstream Test                            2       7      61        30
Diehard OPSO                                     77      14       8         1
Diehard OQSO Test                                96       4       0         0
Diehard DNA Test                                 78      16       6         0
Diehard Count the 1s (stream) Test               91       6       3         0
Diehard Count the 1s Test (byte)                 94       4       2         0
Diehard Parking Lot Test                         96       3       1         0
Diehard Minimum Distance (2d Circle) Test        96       3       1         0
Diehard 3d Sphere (Minimum Distance) Test        95       5       0         0
Example Dieharder Test                           94       6       0         0
Diehard Sums Test                                 0       0       0       100
Diehard Runs Test                                96       3       1         0
Diehard Runs Test                                97       3       0         0
Diehard(er) Craps Test                           99       1       0         0
Diehard(er) Craps Test                           97       3       0         0
Marsaglia and Tsang GCD Test                     99       1       0         0
Marsaglia and Tsang GCD Test                     99       1       0         0
STS Monobit Test                                 97       3       0         0
STS Runs Test                                    98       1       1         0
Example Dieharder Test                           98       1       1         0

Yarrow
Test Name                                    PASSED    WEAK    POOR    FAILED
-----------------------------------------  --------  ------  ------  --------
RGB Bit Distribution Test                        98       1       1         0
RGB Bit Distribution Test                        95       5       0         0
RGB Bit Distribution Test                        98       2       0         0
RGB Bit Distribution Test                        98       2       0         0
RGB Bit Distribution Test                        96       2       2         0
RGB Bit Distribution Test                       100       0       0         0
RGB Bit Distribution Test                        98       1       1         0
RGB Bit Distribution Test                        97       3       0         0
RGB Bit Distribution Test                        95       5       0         0
RGB Bit Distribution Test                        99       1       0         0
RGB Bit Distribution Test                        98       2       0         0
RGB Bit Distribution Test                        97       3       0         0
Diehard(er) Birthdays Test                       95       5       0         0
Diehard OPERM5 Test                              15      20      51        14
Diehard 32x32 Binary Rank Test                   97       2       1         0
Diehard 6x8 Binary Rank Test                     91       6       3         0
Diehard Bitstream Test                            4       8      57        31
Diehard OPSO                                     76      16       8         0
Diehard OQSO Test                                98       2       0         0
Diehard DNA Test                                 81      13       4         2
Diehard Count the 1s (stream) Test               94       3       3         0
Diehard Count the 1s Test (byte)                 92       4       4         0
Diehard Parking Lot Test                         97       2       1         0
Diehard Minimum Distance (2d Circle) Test        94       6       0         0
Diehard 3d Sphere (Minimum Distance) Test        95       4       1         0
Example Dieharder Test                           99       1       0         0
Diehard Sums Test                                 0       0       0       100
Diehard Runs Test                                95       4       1         0
Diehard Runs Test                                98       1       1         0
Diehard(er) Craps Test                           97       3       0         0
Diehard(er) Craps Test                           98       2       0         0
Marsaglia and Tsang GCD Test                     97       2       1         0
Marsaglia and Tsang GCD Test                     96       3       1         0
STS Monobit Test                                 98       2       0         0
STS Runs Test                                    95       4       1         0
Example Dieharder Test                           98       2       0         0
```

Comment: Fortuna uses AES in CTR mode (usually) to generate the output, which is a widely accepted method to generate a pseudorandom bitstream. Chances are you just had bad luck there and Fortuna performed slightly worse (this happens statistically seen) when running the statistic tests.

Comment: To round off this question properly, you absolutely need to  quantify "marginally".  Randomness is only a statistical effect based on percentages, and human acceptance of random changes with time.  It would be useful to know  some of your experimental percentages /outputs.

Comment: Going through the results you have listed, I don't see any statistically significant difference.  If Fortuna was listed as failing Diehard OPERM5 Test 20 times, while Yarrow is listed as failing the same test 14 times, that is within the expected range due to randomness (and that OPERM5 test detects more than 1 failure over 100 runs more likely shows more that the Diehard test is bad, rather than these RNGs are)

Comment: If the test result deltas can be attributed to randomness how can fortuna be evaluated as a better PRNG? If it doesn't perform better with statistical tests compared to its predecessor is fortuna simply better because it's more resistant to attack? What's the motive to upgrade a PRNG from Yarrow to Fortuna?

Comment: @Whome: As you're guessing, it's not "better" because the output is any more random.  It's better because it's more robust against some kinds of attack.  I.e., the improvements are only in the context of an active attacker trying to defeat the RNG.

Comment: A statistical test is a very weak test of a crypto rng, catching only those cases where things are incredibly bad.  As Luis mentioned, the true test of any crypto RNG is "given a long series of outputs which might be from the RNG, and which might be truly random, can an intelligent and clever adversary tell the difference"

Comment: @poncho ... and given (a) snapshot(s) of the internal state.

Comment: @SEJPM: no; the attacker isn't given the internal state; he is given the full description of the RNG (not including the internal state...)

Comment: @poncho it depends on the threat /evaluation model you're considering for your RNG. A common one I've encountered is that the attacker is given the internal state at one point and then it's measured at which point the RNG has re-gained a reasonable amount of entropy. That's the whole point of the Fortuna construction: recover from (punctual) state leaks more relieably than all previous CSPRNGs.

Comment: Indeed, on [the Dieharder home page](http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php) the OPERM5 and Diehard Sums tests are marked as "Suspect" and "Do Not Use" respectively; apparently, they both "appear to have stubborn bugs." I'm quite surprised to see failures in the Bitstream test, however, since it's claimed to be "Good". Whome, have you checked if the built-in AES_OFB generator in Dieharder passes that test?

Comment: To summarize the above points: statistical tests only typically catch particularly egregious errors in an RNG. One RNG can look "better" than another for a given number of tests due to random luck. The improvement of Fortuna over Yarrow isn't in the *quality* of randomness (both are assumed to be effectively optimal, with no attacker advantage) but in Fortuna's ability to recover from an attacker controlling most (but not all) sources of entropy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is the purpose of using the Fortuna PRNG more about security and preventing a 'seed leakage' than it is about the 'quality' of its generated random values?

No. It's not about the 'quality' of generated random values. It's about DieHarder being very paranoic about things that are indeed good quality. Just because your RNG gave you zero three times in a row, it doesn't really mean it's a bad RNG-- this is expected to happen. DieHarder has a known history in failing every RNG in existence from time to time. Your results are simply random; next time you could get opposite results.

> If the test result deltas can be attributed to randomness, how can Fortuna be evaluated as a better PRNG?

DieHarder only decides if output is random-looking or not. It's a blackbox approach. This can only find major mistakes in RNG quality, and DieHarder pushing the limits also detects good RNGs as poor. Cryptographers have a whitebox approach, which gives more details about the cipher, how secure it is etc. Essentially, we want the attacker with the most details/data/attack points given failing an attack (which DieHarder can't simulate well). Yarrow has a less clear approach with trying to determine input quality. Fortuna simplifies this because it uses more randomness pools (and also avoids some problems this way). Also, Yarrow uses algorithms which are now deprecated, and some are broken (not to even mention minor flaws like being inefficient): SHA-1 and 3DES. Those can be changed, but why bother when we have new a standard that uses unbroken algorithms?

Simply said: Fortuna is simpler to implement, uses better primitives out-of-the-box and is generally considered better (because Yarrow has some mistakes that Fortuna fixes). All that with having bigger security margins and better efficiency. There is no reason to consider Yarrow if Fortuna is available.